# multiple fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I hope I can make this question as clear as possible.

I have the following table:

table: phones

```
phone_id | name     | ... ... ... | manufacturer_code
-----------------------------------------------------
1        | samsung  |             | 001 
2        | apple    |             | 002
3        | htc      |             | 003
and so on...
```

I have A LOT of columns (... ... ... means at least 40 different columns like width, height, depth, color, has_bluetooth, ... stuff like that).

Now I want to do this differently, but I have NO IDEA how to start.

How I THINK to do it? (correct me if i'm wrong!)

**1) Store the field names in a different table**

table: phone_fields

```
field_id    | name
--------------------------------
1           | name
2           | width
3           | weight
4           | depth
...         | ...
41          | manufacturer_code
```

**2) Connect the fields with the data for each phone in another table**

table phones

```
row_id    | phone_id    | field_id    | value
------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1           | 1           | samsung
2         | 1           | 2           | 10,50 cm
3         | 1           | 3           | 1 kg
... (and so on).
```

I want this to be searchable/filterable, I have a filter now which filters on brand, color, pricerange, ... and this works fine.

How should you guys do it? Or does anyone have a useful link/tutorial about this? English is not my native language so I don't know exactly how to search for it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: why am I doing this? I want to be able to add extra fields through my admin-panel if necessary (and not via phpmyadmin or something like that).

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I know Jay, but I don't know how to start, that's the problem! It's more of a database design problem.

Comment: You might be overthinking your database design. I don't see a problem with the way you currently have it set up, and what you're wanting to change it to sounds unnecessarily complicated

Comment: Sounds like you want to apply database normalization here.  May not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request always returns the entire set of fields, then leave it in one table

If not, then you can leave only the most important fields in one table, and in the other table place the remaining attributes and link it via foreign key

Comment: I found a problem similar to mine: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/product-attribute-list-design-pattern